# Tag merge [anti-spam] and [spam-prevention]

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

Does anyone want to merge [anti-spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam) and [spam-prevention](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention)? They seem rather redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Because [spam-prevention](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) was less popular than [anti-spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam), I merged the former into the latter.

In the process, I also merged [spam-filter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam-filter) into [anti-spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam). Personally, I like [spam-prevention](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) better, maybe it should now be renamed.

In the end, I'm not even sure if we need [anti-spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam), given that we have [spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam) (and I hope the latter tag isn't used for questions that request help in spamming).

Comment: +1 to just making it all a single [spam] tag

Comment: I'd like to suggest we create a [pro-spam] tag so the confusion never enters the system.

Answer (score 2):

[spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam) & [anti-spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam) merged into [spam-prevention](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention), thanks Oliver for the idea.